Resolve ambiguity between price1 and price2
The constructor of the Product class take two parameters. Price1 and Price2, in that order. Both these parameters are of type double. This causes the constructor to have the following signature:
Product(double, double)

This is ambiguous and is often the cause of bugs because the compiler cannot check the proper values are passed into the proper parameter.
public sealed class Product
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Product(double price1, double price2)
    {
        Price1 = price1;
        Price2 = price2;
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "price1")]
    public double Price1 { get; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "price2")]
    public double Price2 { get; }
}

How can I change the Product class so that this ambiguity is avoided, and correct invocation of the constructor can be verified by the compiler?

"the compiler cannot check the proper values are passed into the proper parameter." How would you propose that this could be done? How would you know whether the Price1 and Price2 properties were assigned the "correct" values (whatever that means)?

"correct invocation of the constructor can be verified by the compiler" The compiler cannot do this. Instead you should focus on having integration tests that verify any uses in your code of the constructor pass the "correct" values.

Let's say these are Latitude and Longitude, I expect the user to provide values in the correct order. First Latitude, second Longitude. I am thinking of using value objects for Price1 and Price2. However I am not if this is the right approach

@PurpleGreen: How would you expect the situation to be resolved in the Latitude and Longitude case? You're already using value types for Price1 and Price2 (as double is a value type). The init-only properties approach suggested by canton7 is one option, but it's not really clear what you're trying to avoid, or what sort of solution you're looking for. (The JSON aspects seem to be irrelevant too.)

@JonSkeet Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my comment; something like this might work I guess public sealed class Product
{
[JsonConstructor]
public Product(Price1 price1, Price2 price2)
{
Price1 = price1;
Price2 = price2;
}
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = “price1”)]
public Price1 Price1 { get; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = “price2)]
public Price2 Price2 { get; }

}

@PurpleGreen Putting code in comments is very difficult to read, I cannot see how, or even if it is, different from the code you have already added to the question . If you need to add additional informations like that can you edit your question and add it there so it can be easily read and understood?

@phuzi The difference is the types: Price1 price1 instead of double price1

@phuzi  The difference is, instead of using  public double Price1 { get; }, do this `public sealed class Product
{
[JsonConstructor]
public Product(Price1 price1, Price2 price2)
{
Price1 = price1;
Price2 = price2;
}
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = “price1”)]
public Price1 Price1 { get; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = “price2)]
public Price2 Price2 { get; }

}`

The point was that it's difficult to read in the comments. Using Price1 price1 just pushes the problem up (down?) the call stack. How can you guarantee that the code used to initialise Price1 and Price2 did so correctly?

In this case the call will be like Price(Price1, Price2) instead of Price(double, double)

Right, but the observation is that you still need to construct Price1 / Price2 appropriately, which means passing in a double, which means passing in the correct double

@PurpleGreen: What's the logical difference between a Price1 and a Price2? Unless they're logically different, representing them with different types feels like an anti-pattern to me.

@JonSkeet You can think of it as Latitude and Longitude which makes up a Location. I cannot share the details of that Price class because of some GDPR rule by my company.

@PurpleGreen: I wouldn't personally recommend having Latitude and Longitude as separate types either, but even less so for different prices unless they're genuinely different (e.g. you'd never want to use one as the other). If it's just "full price" vs "discounted price" I suspect the pain of different types isn't worth the very slight benefit here.

Here's the solution that I found:
public class ProductDto(Price1 price1, Price2 price2)
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "price1")]
    public double Price1 { get; } = price1;
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "price2")]
    public double Price2 { get; } = price2;
}

public record Price1(double Value)
{
    // The Price1 record encapsulates latitude values, providing type safety and clarity
    // it explicitly represents a latitude, not just any double value
    
    //It allows me to implicitly convert an instance of Price1 to a double without needing explicit casting.
    public static implicit operator double(Price1 price1) => price1.Value;
}

This is how I call Price1 and Price2,
new ProductDto(new Price1(request.Price1), new Price2(request.Price2));


You could use required init-only properties instead of a constructor:
public sealed class Product
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "price1")]
    public required double Price1 { get; init; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "price2")]
    public required double Price2 { get; init; }
}

Construction is then:
new Product() { Price1 = ..., Price2 = ... };

The required modifier means that the property must be set during initialisation, and the init accessor means that the property can be set during initialisation but not after.

An alternative is to make sure that you only use named arguments when constructing Product:
new Product(price1: ..., price2: ...);

This however requires discipline to ensure that you always use named arguments with this type. You could use a Roslyn analyzer (such as this one) to raise a warning whenever an annotated type is constructed without named arguments.

Of course, neither of these approaches solves the problem at a type level: they're just focused on trying to reduce the chance that someone passes price1 and price2 in the wrong order because they weren't paying enough attention.
